# What tool can I use to reencode an arbitrary audio file with changing balance?

Tags: audio

I would like to take an arbitrary audio file (such as an `mp3`) and edit it so that the sound "moves" from one speaker to the other every fixed number of seconds.

[image: balance knob]

I would like to simulate someone turning the above knob all the way to the left and then all the way to the right (and back again) every, say 3 seconds.

How could I do this, what tools should I use, or where should I look to learn how to do this?

**EDIT**:

I am using Linux, Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The answer "[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)" should be OS agnostic enough and is open source (both, the program and the answer). I could imagine you won't find an actual balance slider but would have to manipulate the level of the two channels in a way to achieve your desired effect.